# To deploy page layout with feature at the same time of adding content type, the content type Id issue

Tags: content-type, feature, page-layout, object-model

First let me describe my situation:

Now I'm using object model to add two content types (inheriting Pages content type) using the `FeatureActivating` methode in the Feature Receiver. in the same feature, I add a module which deploy two page layouts, using respectively the two newly added content types.

I firstly created the content type using object model, then in the `Elements.xml` for page layouts I copied the `ctype` Id in the url for the **AssociatedContentType**. This was successful. However, when I upgrade the solution to a new site, this won't work any more because the newly added content types Id are no longer the same as the old site.

I know it would be possible using Feature based XAML: I can directly set the Guid of content types here. However I would like to know if there's a way I could do it keeping the object model. Say can I set the Id when creating the content types using the object model so I could know the content type Id for sure when deploying the page layouts. Or is it possible to set dynamically the `AssociatedContentType` in Elements.xml?

Thank you in advance!

**ANSWER**

According to Jan the direct answer is actually here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee581299.aspx
What I need is the overload SPContentType constructor:
`SPContentType constructor (SPContentTypeId, SPContentTypeCollection, String)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create a content type with a set ID programmatically. Please check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798370.aspx which contains a description of how to do so through creating SPContentTypeId-objects.